# Why is there no actual schema for the SCIM core user?

Tags: scim

Simple question here... According to the SCIM specification (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7643) and the seriously limited documentation I could find, there is a "core user schema" provided by SCIM. It is *described* in section 4 of the RFC but this is just a vague description. Where is the *actual schema*? It would be significantly easier to design my own schema if I could see how things are defined in the core user schema. My system only requires/accepts one email address for example, whereas the core schema talks about multiple addresses with different types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's located here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7643#section-8.7.1

For the emails scenario you described, the easiest approach would be to only allow one type(work, other..) and reject any request without a type or with a disallowed type.

Comment: Oh wow how embarrassing! I scoured that RFC looking for this and came up empty... Thank you :)